# Find valid patterns in each line of a file

Tags: java, regex

The following is the problem I am trying to solve:

> Write a program/script to count and print lines which have the
> following pattern
>
> Any 4 char sequence which has a pair of two different characters
> followed by the reverse of that pair e.g xaax or raar. The string is
> not considered valid if the pattern above exist in square brackets.

Following is a simple approach that is possible:

```
private static boolean hasValidPattern(String line) {
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length()-3; i++) {
        char first = line.charAt(i);
        char second = line.charAt(i + 1);
        char third = line.charAt(i + 2);
        char fourth = line.charAt(i + 3);
        if (first == fourth && second == third) {
            if (    (i - 1) >= 0
                    && line.charAt(i - 1) == '['
                    && (i + 4) < line.length() &&
                    line.charAt(i + 4) == ']')
                continue;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this. Probably using regex or something else.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with regex will be as follows:

```
private static boolean hasValidPattern(String line)
{
    return line.matches(".*?(.)(?!\\1)(.)\\2\\1(?:(?!\\])|(?<!\\[.{4})).*");
}
```

**Pattern explanation:**

- `.*?` - Zero or more characters (as few as possible).
- `(.)` - Match one character and capture it in group 1.
- `(?!\\1)` - Not followed by the *same* character.
- `(.)` - Match the second character and capture it in group 2.
- `\\2\\1` - Match what was captured in group 2 followed by what was captured in group 1.
- `(?:(?!\])|(?<!\[.{4}))` - Assert that the previous 4 characters are *not* enclosed in square brackets.
- `.*` - Zero or more characters (as many as possible; i.e., until the end of the line).

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ouk5jf/3) - [Java demo](https://rextester.com/YQZI13512).